# How to get inputs from JTextField similar to Scanner.next()?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextfield

I've been trying to figure out how to receive string and integer inputs from pressing "Enter" in a `JTextField`. I want it to be similar to how `Scanner.next()` receives an input - the program "waits" until an input is given, the it is stored appropriately for further uses. I want to be able to do this because my program asks the user for an input then it displays corresponding texts. Quick example:

> - PROGRAM: "What is your name?"
> - USER: (types in name and hits enter)
> - PROGRAM: "Welcome, (user's input)."

I can extract the contents of a JTextField from a button press, but I don't know how to have the program "wait" for an input ("wait" until the enter is pressed).

```
public static String getStringInput(String prompt)
{
    console.append(prompt);

    String input;

    //Here I need to get the input from a JTextField after I've pressed 
    //enter.

    return input;
}
```

If anyone knows a better way to do this input and response system, that'd be very nice.

thanks.

Comment: myJTextField.getText(); what else do you need?

Comment: your code, together with your description of your requirement, makes little to no sense. can you be more specifc and clear about what you are trying to do? why are you not using the actionPerformed method of the ActionListener listening to the button?

Comment: This is going to be very difficult, and probably won't work the way you are thinking.  The usual method is to determine what happens after the part where you "wait for input", then put that in an ActionListener so that it executes when the users presses Enter or clicks OK. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Comment: *"I've been trying to figure out how to receive string and integer inputs from pressing "Enter" in a JTextField."* Add an `ActionListener` to the text fields. When the field is focused and the user presses 'enter', the listener will be activated.

Comment: *my program asks the user for an input then it displays corresponding texts.* - use a `JOptionPane` to prompt for text. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't let the program wait.** This is a `JFrame` application, not a command line tool, so don't use the mindset of writing command line tools when you develop something that involves a window. Imagine what will happen if the program just stopped and waits after the line `String input;`. The window will freeze and events won't be handled, which is a very bad user experience.

I suggest you do everything inside the event handler for the button click.

```
// at class level
String[] prompts = new String[] { "prompt1", "prompt2", "prompt3" };
int currentPrompt = 0;

// inside the event handler
String text = textfield.getText();
switch (currentPrompt) {
    case 0:
        // text contains the input for prompt1
    case 1:
        // text contains the input for prompt2
    case 2:
        // text contains the input for prompt3
}
```

Inside the switch cases, you could advance to the next prompt by:

```
currentPrompt++; // or set it equal to some other number if you wan to jump around
promptLabel.setText(prompts[currentPrompt]);
textField.setText("");
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to go is with [JOptionPane.showInputDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int)). Application "stops" with a modal dialog, and you grab his input very easy.

Example:

```
//returns null if user closes the dialog.
String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your first name?");
```

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, I think you have to add a listener to your text box. If you are using `JTextField`, it would be:

```
JTextField text = new JTextField();
text.addKeyListener(new KeyListener {
    @Overwrite
    public void keyPressed(event e) {
        if(e.keyCode = SWT.CR) { // SWT.CR is key code of Enter
            // Call your function
        }
    }
}
```

The program will listen to the keyboard event. When you press ENTER, the function inside the listener will run.